# send html page as email in java

Tags: java, email

I am trying to send html page as message.
already send html email through `message.setContent("<html><body><h1>This is actual message</h1></body></html>","text/html" );` these method .Now iwant to send a html page .
like  `message.setContent("street.html","text/html" );`

how to send these below is my full code

```
String to = "to@gmail.com";
  String from = "from@gmail.com";
  Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); 
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

  Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication("from@gmail.com", "from2013");
}});

  try{
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
     message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");
     message.setContent("street.html","text/html" );
     Transport.send(message);
     System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
  }catch (MessagingException mex) {
     mex.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are you trying to send an external HTML page? Like "http://google.com" ? Or just local files that happen to be HTML files?

Comment: Just a local html page

Comment: @user3492997 You want to send the content of a local html file by e-mail, is that right?

Answer (score 2):

A short one-liner for this one:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(new File("home.html")), writer);

message.setContent(writer.toString(), "text/html");
```

**NOTE:**: IOUtils is available in the [Apache Commons IO](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4) library

Comment: copy is depracated

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the contents of "street.html" into a string to be able to send it with the content type "text/html".

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the apache commons mail api

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/apidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/HtmlEmail.html

Answer (score 0):

MimeMessage.setText() method sets a default mime type of text/plain.
But i guess you need text/html. This can be done using MimeMessage.setContent().

You can make use of this code on java side.

```
message.setContent(someHtmlMessage, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to read the content of local file using one of DataHandler impementation. Need to use overloaded method in MiMeMessage Class API which will accept DataHandler object itself.
[MiMeMessage.SetContent(Object, type);](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setContent%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29)

Refer to the API link and google for few samples of usage of method will give the required sloution.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change only

```
String mess=""// it contains html code 
message.setContent(mess,"text/html");
Transport.send(message);
```

it will work